# Can C# Mono create tunnel interfaces multiplatform?

Tags: c#, networking, mono

I haven't been able to find a solution answer on this for the past 2 days:

Can C# Mono, or a supported third party framework, be used to create and manage layer 2 tunnel over a virtual interface across the 3 major platforms (OSX, Windows, Linux)?

At a high-level an application like Hamachi or Tunngle would be a real world example for what I'd like to achieve at a basic level.

The intention behind this question is whether it would be possible to write effective cross-platform code or whether I would have to resort to platform-specific code to implement the virtual interfaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends. Since L2TP is actually accomplished using UDP datagrams, there's no reason why you can't implement it in C#. However, integrating it with the operating system (as a virtual interface driver etc.) is more or less impossible - I'd expect the only real way would be to have a small native wrapper that calls the managed code that does most of the work.

In other words - you can write Hamachi in .NET just fine. Writing the Hamachi Network Adapter is the tricky part. Also, if you just want to add L2TP capabilities to your applications, there's no problem (instead of TcpClient/UdpClient etc., you'd just use your own class that communicates with your L2TP class). However, integrating it to the IP infrastructure does require you to write a driver, which is usually a native-only territory.

It might be that there are some ready-to-use solutions that have the virtual network adapter which can call DLLs, but I'm not aware of any. A very unsafe way would also be to create hooks on Socket calls, but I'm not going to elaborate since that's extremely tricky and a bad idea overall :D

In other words, you have the option to use a hybrid approach - have the minimal native drivers for all the platforms you want to support, and let them call your managed library to do all the real work - the managed library can then be platform independent (as long as Mono is supported there :)).

Now, each OS probably has its own VPN client, which you could concievably use from .NET. However, that also means that your application will have to be able to support each of these OSes and their different VPN clients separately - and that *will* be tricky.

If you want to go the way of writing your own network interface driver, a good way to start on Windows is the Driver Development Kit, which has some sample source code for NIC drivers. Windows uses NDI (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Driver_Interface_Specification), which has some support even on *nix family of OSes, so it might be possible to do this relatively easily - but don't forget, you're still writing a driver. Unless you have significant experience with C/C++/ASM and OS kernels and driver models, you're probably out of your league here. This is the stuff that leads to BSODs :)

There's also some related technologies like TDI (Transport Driver Interface) or WFP (Windows Filtering Platform) which could be used to do all this in user-space, rather than kernel/driver-space. However, those are Windows technologies. You'll have to find the equivalents on the other OSes you want to support, and you'll have to do some magic to make it all work in one cross-platform application. And while doing all this, you want to maintain performance - which requires very careful programming in .NET (it's easy to write reliable code in .NET, but it's harder to get cutting-edge performance. C/C++/ASM is quite the opposite - it's relatively easy to do things fast, but reliability suffers).

Comment: Great comprehensive answer. Its not what I really wanted to hear, but you've given me all I need to move forward, thanks!